# Why does “np.inf // 2” result in NaN and not infinity?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, nan

I’m slightly disappointed that `np.inf // 2` evaluates to `np.nan` and not to `np.inf`, as is the case for normal division.

Is there a reason I’m missing why `nan` is a better choice than `inf`?

Comment: It could be that `floor_divide` is more efficient than doing both operations separately.

Comment: I'd say `inf` would be an incorrect result of integer division because `inf` is not an integer. Now `nan` isn't an integer either, but at least it somehow expresses the fact that there is no correct answer to the question that was asked, i.e. there is no integer `x` such that `x*2` equals `inf`. That's my take on it anyway.

Comment: @0x5453 - You are correct. So the question is why, here too, `nan` was considered a better choice than `inf`?

Comment: @sepp2k - Would you consider then `np.floor(np.inf)` resulting in `np.inf` a correct result? You could claim there is no correct integer answer to this question as well.

Comment: @sepp2k I agree with your answer in general, although I’m not sure the reason is because np.inf is not an integer. 13.2 // 2 returns 6.0. 13.2 and np.inf are both type float.

Comment: @sepp2k `float('inf')*2` returns `inf`.

Comment: @Ethan I still agree with the answer (that is in the comments for some reason). Integer division yields an integer. Yes the typing was changed such that it will be an integer represented as a float when floating point numbers are involved, but their is no integer representation of infinity.

Comment: @MarkRansom I think what was said still holds considering `float('inf')` isn't an integer

Comment: @Aaron it's not called integer division though, it's called floor division.  That means floating point numbers can be included without introducing any anomalies.

Comment: @Aguy yes, because `floor(x)` always differs from `x` by some finite value between 0 and 1, and the result of that subtraction would be `Inf` (according to IEEE semantics) no matter what value in that range was chosen.

Comment: @Aguy the general rule is that operations on Inf should give the limiting value of the same operation on ordinary numbers, unless that limit is indeterminate, in which case you get NaN. So `floor(inf) == inf` and `floor(-inf) == -inf`. And indeed POSIX `floor` *does* give that result.

Comment: I don't have an IEEE-754 spec at hand but according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/floating-point-rules) IEEE-754 requires *INF - INF = NaN, (+/-)INF / (+/-)INF = NaN, and (+/-)INF * 0 = NaN*. No idea about INF/x though

Comment: @phuclv: Pretty sure INF divided by anything except INF or NaN is still +-INF.  But that's for regular division, not floor-division; IDK if IEEE-754 defines that operation at all; C doesn't have it and real-world FPUs don't have it.  (You can set the rounding mode to truncate or towards -Inf and still get Inf.)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'm going to be the person who [just points at the C level](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/945d3cbf2e8e756ed16c3ec51106e6157abb2698/Objects/floatobject.c#L671C2-L672C25) implementation without any attempt to explain intent or justification:

```
*mod = fmod(vx, wx);
div = (vx - *mod) / wx;
```

It looks like in order to calculate `divmod` for floats (which is called when you just [do floor division](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/945d3cbf2e8e756ed16c3ec51106e6157abb2698/Objects/floatobject.c#L732)) it first calculates the modulus and `float('inf') %2` only makes sense to be `NaN`, so when it calculates `vx - mod` it ends up with `NaN` so everything propagates nan the rest of the way.

So in short, since the implementation of floor division uses modulus in the calculation and that is `NaN`, the result for floor division also ends up `NaN`

Comment: If this really is the C code that implements floor division for floats, it's probably correct but very unsatisfying.  You're really just kicking the can down the road.

Comment: yeah I recognize that, I'd very much like to see a better answer. However it is possible the reasoning is "no one has really considered it until now" in which case I'm afraid this may be the only answer.

Comment: Why not just have a single line where `*mod` in `div = (vx - *mod) / wx;` is replaced by the part after the equal mark above it ?

Comment: @rautamiekka that is the source code calculating both the modulus and floor division, it needs to retain the modulus.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen So the value is reused later ?

Comment: @rautamiekka If you follow the link in the answer, you will see for yourself how it is used.

Answer (score 25):

Floor division is defined in relation to modulo, both forming one part of the divmod operation.

> #### [Binary arithmetic operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)
>
> The floor division and modulo operators are connected by the following
> identity: `x == (x//y)*y + (x%y)`. Floor division and modulo are also
> connected with the built-in function divmod(): `divmod(x, y) == (x//y, x%y)`.

This equivalence cannot hold for `x = inf` — the remainder `inf % y` is undefined — making `inf // y` ambiguous. This means `nan` is at least as good a result as `inf`. For simplicity, [CPython actually only implements divmod and derives both // and % by dropping a part of the result](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b5f87b93a542082551c67538523d318f0d46e16e/Objects/floatobject.c#L698) — this means `//` inherits `nan` from divmod.

Answer (score 1):

Infinity is not a number. For example, you [can't even say](https://www.quora.com/What-is-infinity-minus-infinity) that infinity - infinity is zero. So you're going to run into limitations like this because NumPy is a *numerical* math package. I suggest using a *symbolic* math package like [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/) which can handle many different expressions using infinity:

```
import sympy as sp

sp.floor(sp.oo/2)
sp.oo - 1
sp.oo + sp.oo
```